# usb wifi adapter "lsusb" 0e8d:7610 Mediatek

Tags: wireless

Please I'd like to know if the solution posted by "Pilot6": [How to install TP-LINK T2UH Wireless adapter Driver (Ralink mt7610u)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674116/how-to-install-tp-link-t2uh-wireless-adapter-driver-ralink-mt7610u)
Can work for me too,I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS,but I'm a beginner.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not running Ubuntu 16.04 nor do I have the device, so I don't know for certain. However, you can find out yourself easy enough. Follow the steps up through `make` and stop. Did the process end in an error or did it compile the driver module and end in `MODPOST`? If the latter, just continue and you're all set.

If the process ends in an error, then we can conclude that the circa-2013 package is too old for your 4.4.0-xx kernel version. Then ask a new question and ask if there *IS* a method to make it work in 4.4.0-xx and later. Until I learn more, my answer is that there is not.

Comment: If the solution above is old,do you think that is better don't use it?I always forget that I copied,because I don't have a CD player,all the Cd that comes with the adapter,the question is can I use it and how?because I'm unable to run it.Thank you

Comment: I'm saying try it up to `make` and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry "chili555" I have a question, before I insist with new try with driver installation,I have, with Windows,a connection speed of about 280Mbps wired.How much should have I with Ubuntu?To be correct I use Ubuntu on a pc with a network card that can reach no more 100 Mbps.Thank you

Comment: I haven't any information about that specific device. I would think it should do, at a minimum, 54 Mbps.

Comment: Can you,please,help me to understand if there is something wrong,because I can reach no more than 25-30 Mbps,wired.I installed 16.04LTS (for the second time) at the end of the year,to be sure that everything is OK.Thank you

Comment: "My wired internet is slow" is a different question from can I get my MT7610 USB wireless working. I suggest you start a new question.

Comment: Sorry "chili555" if I'm disturbing you,I'd like to have your opinion about this post http://i.imgur.com/Hp0oNrk.jpg.Is it so unclear?and do you think that using,back to the old question,the wireless adapter can improve my wireless speed,now is about 17 Mbps.Thank you

Comment: The only way to know is to try the driver as I suggested and then do a proper speed test; here, for example: http://www.speedtest.net/

Comment: I tried the driver,the only "good news"is that I saw,for the first time a solid,not blinking like on the other adapter I'm using with Windows,green light.The download speed I'd say the same.At this point I can't do nothing to improve my download speed,have you same ideas?Curiosity,are you using Ubuntu?and which speed can you reach?ok,it depends which pc you are using,but if isn't possible to use 5 Ghz,which is the top speed that can be reached with Ubuntu or other distros?Thank you

Comment: Yes, I use Ubuntu on all four computers in my home. My wireless speed, like yours, depends on your internet service provider, router, wireless card and driver version. Here is a recent test on this very computer (wireless): http://www.dslreports.com/speedtest/7373978 Depending on the hardware and driver, it is entirely possible to use 5 gHz as I am right now.

Comment: What do you suggest to me?keep my small pc like it is and forget adapters?Thank you

Comment: Have you tried all the steps here? http://askubuntu.com/questions/872352/ubuntu-14-wifi-doesnt-work/872362#872362

Comment: "lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2" doesn't give output."sudo iwlist wlan0 scan"interface doesn't support scanning.I have 2,4 GHz on channel 6, 20 GHz,I tried it's the best and WPA2,"IPv6 "no connection(unchangeable).What do you think?Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you've done all the right things. What does http://www.speedtest.net/ tell us now?

Comment: PLEASE DON'T MOVE TO CHAT-Now I have about 20 Mbps wireless.Please what do think about "Ubuntu Tweak"just for cleaning?Is it safe?Thank you

Comment: I have never used it and have no opinion.

Comment: It's me again,sorry,I have a question for you.Can you explain why the download speed with   Chromium is:wireless 21+ wired 31+ and with Firefox is: wireless 24- wired 10+.Thank you

Comment: With speedtest.net or some other way?

Comment: Always with Speedtest.net and the same server.Look with Firefox wireless is more than wired and the wired speed with Chromium/Firefox.What do you think?

Comment: What I think is that this has gone far, far off the topic of the original question. Please start a new question about the speed of your ethernet connection. Include as many details as possible including: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A2` My apologies to the moderators.